# "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" Google Geocoding don't recognize my API KEY

Tags: api, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

When I'm consulting to the Google Geocoding API it response whit the error "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT", I'm using an API KEY but google dont recognize it, because when I do the request, I saw the panel (https://console.developers.google.com) and donth have any request. An example of the URL than I'am using is:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=CALLE+11+#+8+-+26,+Cucuta,+Norte+de+Santander,+Colombia+&key=API_KEY
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to URL encode the address string before pass it to the request, otherwise any special symbol will break the request.

https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/overview#BuildingURLs

In your example the special symbol that breaks the request is #, it should be replaced by %23.

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=CALLE%2011%20%23%208%20-%2026%2C%20Cucuta%2C%20Norte%20de%20Santander%2C%20Colombia&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Hope this helps!